# CountVectorizer ignores Upper Case

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

What is the reason why CountVectorizer ignores word in upper case?

```
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None,analyzer='word',token_pattern='.*',max_features=None)
text = ['this','is','a','Test','!']
fcv = cv.fit_transform(list)
fcv = [cv.vocabulary_.get(t) for t in text]
print fcv
```

returns

```
[5, 3, 2, None, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused as `lowercase` is set to `True` by default in `CountVectorizer`, add `lowercase=False`.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, analyzer='word', token_pattern='.*',
        max_features=None, lowercase=False)
```

Comment: Yes. Although, *probably* you just want `[cv.vocabulary_.get(t.lower()) for t in text]` instead of having different features for `"Test"` and `"test"`....

Comment: oops I didn't notice there is a parameter for that. Thank you! http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform

Comment: @Sindico yes, **but you probably don't want to use that parameter!** There's a good reason why it defaults to `True`.